# How to fix next generation java plugin?

Tags: applet, java, java-7

We are facing issue when we disable java's next generation plugin plugin [image]

When we disable this option and try to communicate with javascript with applet the Internet explorer hangs irrespective of its version .

The applet can be found here:
http://jdk6.java.net/nonav/plugin2/liveconnect/ArrayAccess.html

It works perfectly with the option as enabled .

But as a requirement we need the option as disabled , can anyone guide us a possible workaround or fix for the same .

Comment: Its a part of our requirement

Comment: Acually QA folks were testing the same using some silk tool , which require this property to be disabled to get the same working

Comment: Maybe you should look into getting a better testing tool.

Comment: That correct , but till the time we try out the new tool we are looking  forward to possibly find at least a workaround for the same, as qa folks are stuck in this

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your requirement. I think it is just legacy requirement that was created in period from Java 1.6.15 to Java 1.6.30. In this version range "next generation" really must be disabled. In latest versions "next generation" must be enabled. Starting from Java 8 there is no such option, e.g. "next generation" enabled by default.